# Get ID from Ravendb query

Tags: ravendb

I am using the clientAPI to query an index (Cards) in RavenDB so:

```
Dim cards = Raven.CurrentSession.Query(Of Cards)("Cards").ToArray()
```

This works well and returns all the documents, but how can I get the ID of the documents it returns?

Comment: I could not understand why it was not in the entity. If I made a property called id, Raven should put the Id in it automatically. I did not know it was case-sensitive :) The property needed to be called Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eystein,

for each of the returned cards, you do

Raven.CurrentSession.Advanced.GetDocumentId(card)

Comment: Thank you. I found a way of putting it inside each entity now, but this worked also :)